# CentOS crontab job is not executing

Tags: unix, cron, centos

I am trying to set up a crontab job to back up a mysql DB every day at a specific time.
I do the following steps (as root):

1. `crontab -e`
2. `00 11 * * * root /root/my_Backups/productionbDB-backup.sh >> mybackup.log 2>&1`
3. `service crond restart`

I waited to be 11 am, but nothing happened.
I confirmed that if the command `/root/my_Backups/productionbDB-backup.sh` is issued from the command line, as root, it creates the backup.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`00 11 * * * root /root/my_Backups/productionbDB-backup.sh >> mybackup.log 2>&1` -> what is the `root` word doing there? What you should have is `00 11 * * * /root/my_Backups/productionbDB-backup.sh >> mybackup.log 2>&1`

Comment: ah damn, I thought I needed to also add the user who executes it...

Answer (score 0):

You have used the format for installing crontabs into system wide /etc/cron.d/

`<time spec> <user> <command>`

As you are installing into a users personal crontab (for example on CentOS /var/spool/cron/{user}) using `crontab -e` the format ommits the user specification

`<time spec> <command>`

More information available in the cron manpage [here](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/cron/cron.8)